# Build failed in xcode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, build, assertion

I have upgraded my iphone sdk from 3.1.3 to 3.2.3. But now i have a problem. The project i m working on is not compiling in new sdk. I have changed the target info settings also i.e. base sdk is set to iphone device 4.0. I have follwing build error:

```
Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE in         /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-       1691/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTargetBuildContext.m:2061
Details:  Assertion failed: [filePath isAbsolutePath]
Object:   <PBXTargetBuildContext:0x201779de0>
Method:   -setHeadermapToolInvocation:forFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x20091e040>{name = (null), num = 5}
Backtrace:
0  0x00000001002857d8 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
1  0x00000001002dab3f _XCAssertionFailureHandler (in DevToolsCore)
2  0x0000000100282342 -[PBXTargetBuildContext setHeadermapToolInvocation:forFilePath:] (in DevToolsCore)
3  0x0000000100141a6b -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
4  0x0000000100381aa5 -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:additionalProperties:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
5  0x000000010015b3cd -[XCResourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
6  0x000000010013d4a8 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
7  0x000000010015b0e3 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
8  0x000000010015b031 -[XCResourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
9  0x000000010012d1eb -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
10  0x0000000100128a19 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
11  0x0000000100124ba5 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
12  0x0000000100123b62 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
13  0x00007fff83eed0dc __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
14  0x00007fff83eecfad -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
15  0x000000010012357a -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
16  0x00007fff83eed0dc __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
17  0x00007fff83eecfad -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
18  0x000000010012309b -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
19  0x0000000100122e0d -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
20  0x00007fff829f9e99 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
21  0x00007fff8845ff8e _pthread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
22  0x00007fff8845fe41 thread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

I have deleted build folder and trying to clean all targets but it does not work.

Comment: Hey. I know it's been a while, but do you remember how you solved this? I'm encountering the same problem with XCode 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build an iPad app or an iPhone app?
As far as I know 3.2.x is for iPad.
Moreover, are you trying to run it on the device or on the simulator? if you are running on the simulator, make sure it is set correctly in the project settings.

Comment: I am building iPhone app. It neither builds for device nor for simulator. I have checked almost all project settings.

Comment: Set the base SDK to 3.1.3 and not 3.2. If you are building an iPhone and not an iPad app, there is no need for you to use the 3.2.x version.